# looking for fast way to handle cell matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a big cell with each element carrying a collection of index of a big matrix (M). I have some operations of the elements of M specified by those indices like

```
N=1000;
P=100;
M=rand(N, N);
K=zeros(N, P);
for n=1:N
  IND{n} = [randi(N, 1, randi(200))];
end

tic
for m=1:P
  for n=1:N
    K(n, m) = sum(sum(M(IND{n})));
  end
end
toc

tic
for m=1:P
  Z = cellfun(@(idx) sum(M(idx)), IND, 'UniformOutput', false);
  K(:, m) = [Z{:}];
end
toc
```

the last loop if pretty slow. Is that any way to use one statement instead of a loop to do the same thing? Thanks.

Comment: Check [cellfun](http://goo.gl/0jj3z).

Comment: thanks. I follows the help and get the following code Z=cellfun(@(x) sum(sum(M(x))), IND, 'UniformOutput', false); K = [Z{:}]; but it is even slower than the loop code :(

Comment: your minimal code doesn't work... "Function 'subsindex' is not defined for values of class 'cell'. " Can you show us what you actually did?

Comment: Thanks. I've updated the post and put all code tested in matlab R2013a.

Comment: U can save some time by defining anonymous function out of the loop `sumFhandle = @(idx) sum(M(idx));` and then in loop `cellfun(sumFhandle, IND, 'UniformOutput', false);`

Comment: Thanks. But it only helps very little. Since the code will be applied to a even much bigger matrix for so many times, it will be running in the server for days or week. So I am still looking for better code to import the efficiency.

Comment: Are you able to convert to a matrix using `cell2mat`? Then you could use a vectorized solution which might be faster. If your data really follows the form of just random numbers as in your example then you should be able to use `cell2mat` and pad with zeros?

Comment: I don't understand how vectorized form will help this. The number of the elements in the cell element are different. Also since the cell elements are used as index, if I pad it with zero, it might not work as well.

Answer (score 1):

Because Z never actually changes and cellfun does return a uniform output the following is ~ 100 times faster.

```
K=repmat(cellfun(@(idx) sum(M(idx)), IND)',1,P);
```

Comment: wow, amazing, it is really fast. I have my code modified to use your case, it solve the problem.

Comment: but I just think of another issue might causing above statement to fail (sorry for that but actually I have two questions but I didn't realize it is a problem at the beginning). If M has to be changed within the loop (for m=1:P ... end), then above statement is not longer valid, right?

Comment: % The repmat now just moves into cellfun eg.
M=arrayfun(@rand,N*ones(P,1),'UniformOutput', false);
K2=cellfun(@(idx,M) sum(M(idx)), repmat(IND',1,P),repmat(M',N,1));

Comment: Thanks for the code. It works but the performance is not good. I compare it with a loop version, it is even worse than the loop case. Also, since it use repmat, when the size of M is big, it waste too much of memory :(